# Need to use hyphen in a Builder function name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, builder

I'm trying to use Builder to build up a xml document for project I am working on. The xml has a very strict structure so I can't change it.
The problem I am running into is this. I am trying to add a child to a node `"linking-phrase-list"`
The name of the child must be `"linking-phrase"`. So in order to do this I would call:

```
test = Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.map {
    xml.send(:"linking-phrase-list") {
      xml.linking-phrase("label" => "edge1", "id" => "idedge1")
    }
  }
end
```

Of course then ruby interprets this as `(xml.linking)-phrase()` which is not at all what I want. So I need to know if there is some way I can convince ruby that is one function call not two? That or tell nokogiri that I mean that when I'm not using that function.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `tag!` method provided by builder for exactly this purpose.

```
test = Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.map {
    xml.tag!("linking-phrase-list") {
      xml.tag!("linking-phrase", "label" => "edge1", "id" => "idedge1")
    }
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you have the answer in your question, use `send` method:

```
require 'nokogiri'

test = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.map {
    xml.send(:"linking-phrase-list") {
      xml.send(:"linking-phrase", "label" => "edge1", "id" => "idedge1")
    }
  }
end

puts test.to_xml
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<map>
  <linking-phrase-list>
    <linking-phrase label="edge1" id="idedge1"/>
  </linking-phrase-list>
</map>
```